# Error in MySQL statement in WHERE clause

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I am trying to get a value "startDate" and "endDate" from my form:

```
<form>
        <input id="startDate"/>                     
        <input id="endDate"/>
    </form
```

The form is connected to a javascript, which from there goes to a MySQL database. The problem is that every time I run SQL query in my servlet i get the following error:

SQLException caught: Unknown column 'startDate' in 'where clause'

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?
have a nice day from Julie

EDITED CODE: I have tried to edited my code. I now get the error at: Date startDate; , where it says: "Duplicate local variable startDate". That is of course because I have 
String startDate = req.getParameter("startDate"); . I dont have to use this anymore?
        package WorkPackage;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
        String startDate = req.getParameter("startDate");
        String endDate= req.getParameter("endDate");
        try {
            //Load database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            //Getting the data from database
            Date startDate;                                             
            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata WHERE Date = ?";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setDate(1,startDate);
                //pst.setString(2,endDate);
            //Show the result from database
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            float Allday_hours_sum = 0;
                while (rs.next()){                                      
                    Allday_hours_sum += rs.getFloat("Allday_hours"); 


            }   
                res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          
                res.getWriter().print(Allday_hours_sum); 


            pst.close();


        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED:
This is how my database looks like:
http://postimg.org/image/3sbzplg9d/

This is my javascript where I am getting some values out from my calendar:

```
<form>
        <input id="startDate"/>                     
        <input id="endDate"/>
    </form>
    <div id="startresult"></div>
    <div id="endresult"></div>
    <script>

    $(function(){
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
                $('.selected-date').html(dateText);

                $.ajax({
                      url: "../getHoursSQL",
                      type: "post",
                      data: JSON,
                      success: function(data){
                          start: $("#startDate").val();
                          alert("success");
                          $("#startresult").html(data);

                      },
                      error:function(){
                          alert("failure");
                          $("#startresult").html('there is error while submit');
                      }  
                    });
            }
        });
    });

    $(function(){
            $("#endDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
                    $('.selected-date').html(dateText);

                    $.ajax({
                          url: "../getHoursSQL",
                          type: "post",
                          data: JSON,
                          success: function(data){
                              end: $("#endDate").val();
                              alert("success");
                              $("#endresult").html(data);
                          },
                          error:function(){
                              alert("failure");
                              $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                          }  
                        });
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: show your table columns please.

Comment: Have you checked case-sensitivity?

Comment: Does the Workdata table have a startDate column?

Comment: Hello eveyone. Thanks for your quick answers I have just edited my question. Maybe you can see something? :-)

Comment: There is no startDate and endDate in your table so you can not fetch data like this!!

Comment: can you print this line in console? what it gives you? `String startDate = req.getParameter("startDate");`

Comment: As four respondents have pointed out, your SQL statement refers to columns called startDate and endDate, but you do not have those columns in your table.  You need to change the where clause of your SQL statement.  And you have a nice day too, Julie.

Comment: Hello again. When I run my servlet I get the error:
SQLException caught: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

Comment: Julie, that would indicate that you are calling something like `setString` or `setDate`, and passing 2 as the parameter index, but you've only got one `?` in the SQL of your prepared statement.

Comment: Julie, please don't keep editing your code here as people give you answers, because it means the answers don't match the question any more, which makes the question useless for future users of the site.  If  you have a new question, it's best to ask it as a new question.  Remember that the primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a long-lived database of questions and answers that fit the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your image (it's rather cluttered, far too much information) there's no column called startDate in table Workdata. All columns in an SQL statement must actually exist in the appropriate tables.

Did you mean column Date?
If you did, you shouldn't use

```
pst.setString(1, startDate);
```

because that's only good for setting string columns (varchar, longtext, etc). Instead, you should use

```
pst.setDate(1, startDate);
```

where `startDate` here is a `java.sql.Date`, not a `String`

EDIT:

In response to your updates, I have updated my answer.

The line

```
Date startDate;
```

surely won't compile, as `startDate` is already a declared as a String. Even if you changed the name, you have not set the date given in the request parameter.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = format.parse(req.getParameter("startDate"); 
pst.setDate(1,startDate);
```

You'll need to change the string in the SimpleDateFormat constructor to suit your needs (the format of your date string). The above code will work for dates formatted like 2014-03-11. Your format might be different. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Hello Nick. Thanks for your answer. I have updated my answer now. How does it look do you think? I would be happy if you have time to give your opinion :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error it couldn't find the column in the table. Please check your table Workdata has field `startDate`

And also it is not good to pass date as String and also be careful to use `=` operator to compare date or datetime filed. 
My advise is to compare datetime use `BETWEEN` operator.

```
... WHERE startDate BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Comment: Hello Rohitha. Thanks a lot for your answer. I just edited my question. Can you see anything else I have done wrong here?

Comment: according to your table, field name is Date. so sql should be `SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata WHERE \`Date\` BETWEEN  ? and ?` . Note: use `\`` before and after field name Date. because I think Date is a keyword in Mysql. Note that `between` operator implies Date greater than or equal first value and less than or equal second value. for more details [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: Hello Rohitha. I have updated my code. Does it look more resioble now?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get data then you should this instead.

```
Date startDate;
//use SqlDate instead of string.

String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 60)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata WHERE Date = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setDate(1,startDate);
```

Now you have something in your output as you have `date` column in your table.

UPDATE :

If you want to use `String` datatype for date parameter.. Remove `Date startDate` and keep it what you have.. After that Parse your date using SimpleDateFormatter.

For EG.

```
String startDate = req.getParameter("Date");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//surround below line with try catch block as below code throws checked exception
Date start = sdf.parse(startDate);
out.println(sdf.format(startDate)); //this is what you want yyyy-MM-dd
```

Thanks..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried to play around with the code. I updated my question. How does it looks now? Thanks again for your time. From Julie